# too many argument to the function

Tags: c++

i'm getting this error in my terminal: too many arguments to function `'bool Verify(int, int)'`.I think it has something to do with the function but i can't figure out any solution so far. I'm kinda new to c++ so i hope i could get some guidance to solving this problem.

my code look like this:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
bool Verify(int number,int size);

int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cin>>number;
    int size= floor(log10(number))+1;
    int array[size];

    if(Verify(number,size,array)==true){
        std::cout<<"this number is verify";
    }else{
        std::cout<<"this number isn't verify";
    }
    return 0;
}
bool Verify(int number,int size,int array[])
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    int digit=number%10;
    number=number/10;
    array[i]=digit;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<size;j+2){
        if(array[j]%2==1)
        {
            sum=sum+array[j];
        }else if(array[j]>4){
            sum=sum+2*array[j]-9;
        }else
        {
            sum=sum+2*array[j];
        }
        
    }
    if(sum%10==0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're learning C++ from an outdated source. Stop uing "C" style arrays. E.g. your verify function should use `std::vector<int>&`  not  `int array[]`. See [std:;vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Good  sources to learn C++ from are a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declaration and definition of `Verify` contradict each other:

Declaration:

```
bool Verify(int number,int size);
```

Definition:

```
bool Verify(int number,int size,int array[]) //...
```

Fix your declaration to reflect the definition.

---

Not part of the question: you've set up for an infinite loop here:

```
for(int j=0;j<size;j+2)
```

`j` is never updated, so `j<size` will always be true.